# PIP saves the day on Fedora 25 for No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets' error..WHY?

Tags: fedora, python, qt, pip

In Fedora 25, I am trying to compile Python 3+ using QT 5 and run into the following error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/anki/aqt/qt.py", line 17, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'
```

The new QTWebEngine should contain this package, and here is a list of the dependencies I have installed for the project:

```
dnf install -y python3 
dnf install -y python3-devel 
dnf install -y qt5 
dnf install -y python3-qt5 
dnf install -y python3-qt5-devel 
dnf install qt5-qtwebengine-devel
dnf install qt5-qtwebengine
```

Perhaps it was a `$PATH` problem?
For giggles, I tried to run

```
pip3 install pyqt5
```

and BOOM..PIP saves the day. The `$PATH` still looked identical before/after, just like:

```
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/tcruise/.local/bin:/home/tcruise/bin
```

Does PIP have some mystical unicorn powers, or am I missing the point here?

Thanks for your trouble folks.

Comment: Yes, you're missing the point.  Qt5 is a C++ library.  PyQt5 is the Python module for Qt5 bindings.  Qt5 can happily work without PyQt5.  The other way around however, PyQt5 can't possibly work without Qt5.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I understand that but as you can see in the original dnf dependency installs both were installed, QT5 first then Python3-QT5, however, looking at the original error it couldn't tell that PYQT5 was installed despite all of the dnf dependencies installing successfully

Comment: Then it's me who missed the point.  If modules installed with the system's package manager are not directly usable then either you stumbled upon a bug in the bundled packages, or you messed up your Python by installing things with `pip`.  Mixing `dnf` with `pip` is almost guaranteed to do that eventually.  Still, something doesn't look right above: are you sure `/usr/lib/anki/aqt/qt.py` isn't supposed to be in `/usr/lib64/...`?

Comment: @SatoKatsura its just the directory where I cloned that repository, is there a difference?

Comment: Yes, on x86 Linux `/usr/lib` is used for 32-bits applications.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Is it just a naming convention for the folder organization?

Comment: No, it's actually used for loading 32-bits libraries.  Don't put unrelated junk in there, things will start crashing if you do.

Comment: So to semi-conclude, perhaps next time we could try replacing the dnf python packages with pip

Comment: You should decide from the very beginning whether you want to stay with the system's Python and package manager, or you want to run multiple versions of Python and install modules manually.  If you use both `dnf` and `pip` there is a good chance modules installed with `dnf` won't "see" the ones installed with `pip`, and the other way around.  Actually, if you're doing a lot of Python it's probably cleaner to uninstall the system's Python altogether (provided it isn't required by the OS, of course).

Comment: I faced the same problem with Spyder, so there's definitely something funny going on there. I went inside the installed packages' directories and the dnf-installed version did not have QtWebEngineWidgets.so, while pip's version had.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually pretty simple to explain: you hadn't installed PyQt5's QtWebEngine component.

(In Fedora 28...)

```
$ sudo dnf install python3-qt5-webengine
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                    Arch        Version              Repository    Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 python3-qt5-webengine      x86_64      5.10.1-4.fc28        updates      113 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 113 k
Installed size: 449 k
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

Then, as now, the PyQt5 package was not monolithic. Certain components are broken out into subpackages.

```
$ sudo dnf list python3-qt5-\*
Installed Packages
python3-qt5-base.x86_64                    5.10.1-4.fc28                @updates
python3-qt5-devel.x86_64                   5.10.1-4.fc28                @updates
python3-qt5-webengine.x86_64               5.10.1-4.fc28                @updates
python3-qt5-webkit.x86_64                  5.10.1-4.fc28                @updates
```

Comment: This could very well have been due to the current state of the dnf repos upstream on the snapshot of fedora (25) at the time, so while I feel this answer is good I'm not sure if I can mark is as the solution as I no longer have the environment active.

Comment: @Rice I mean, that's fine, but it's _still_ the case even today in F33 that `python3-qt5-{webkit,webengine}` are separate packages from the rest of `python3-qt5` (aka PyQt5). The same way that Riverbank's own PyPi distributions come as separate `pyqt5` and `pyqtwebengine` wheels. (They don't distribute a `pyqtwebkit` wheel since QtWebKit is no longer part of the Qt distribution, but someone else does.)